# Is it bad practice to add GameComponents and DrawableGameComponents outside of the main initialization method?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I'm working on a snake game that has multiple game objects (snakes, apples, obstacles), and game modes (classic, adventure), that are DrawableGameComponents. Is it OK that I'm adding them as needed instead of in the main initialization method?

If not, how should I go about drawing and updates components of my game that need to be added in other methods?

If yes, is there any way to get the initialization or load overridden methods to run? Or is making my own load method and calling it right after adding the component how it should be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can add (`Drawable`)`GameComponent`s at any time. When you add them *before* `Game.Initialize` (eg: in your game constructor), they will have their `Initialize` method called when `Game.Initialize` is called.

If you add them ***after*** `Initialize` is called on your game class, then they will have their `Initialize` method called when they are **added** to the `Game.Components` collection.

Note that the upshot of this is that there is a small window in your game class's `Initialize` method, in between you calling `base.Initialize()` and returning, where game components will **not** be initialized!

Note that `Game.Initialize` will call `LoadContent`, so adding components in your `LoadContent` method also will cause them to not be initialized. Although adding components from a game *component* `Initialize` method *will* work.

`DrawableGameComponent.Initialize` calls `DrawableGameComponent.LoadContent` (so don't skip any `base` calls in methods that you `override`).

---

You could also add them at the start of your game and then toggle the `Enabled` and `Visible` properties as required.

Alternately, you could skip the game components system all together. It's basically just a list of objects with virtual `Update` and `Draw` methods (et cetera). This way you can program things to do *exactly* what you want.

Comment: The initialization method only gets called for certain objects, at certain points, and sometimes doesn't get called at all. More specifically my main menu component doesn't init when being added but my game modes do. If i add a component where i add the main menu the previously working component doesnt init. Do you know why?

Comment: There is - what I would describe as - a bug in XNA, where the initialization mode switch-over does not happen until after `Initialize` returns. See my edit.