# In Monogame, can/should SpriteBatch be instantiated in the Initialize method as opposed to the LoadContent method?

Tags: c#, monogame, spritebatch

By default the `SpriteBatch` instance used is instantiated in the `LoadContent` method of `Game1`.

For example [see here](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=understanding_the_code)

However a `SpriteBatch` only requires a `GraphicsDevice` object to be instantiated. Said `GraphicsDevice` is actually already available when the `Initialize` method is created, so my question is why is the `SpriteBatch` created in `LoadContent`?

I think that both methods are run only once per game, so don't see why you can't/shouldn't instantiate the `SpriteBatch` object in the `Initialize` method?

Comment: Your question got me curious and I found [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86104/why-does-gamecomponent-have-an-initialize-method/86108#86108) which you might find helpful. I would be very interested to see if it's still possible to trigger a device reset in MonoGame and more importantly if it actually causes issues having code in the wrong method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDE has a decompiler, you may want to explore the base `Game` class. You will see:

```
protected virtual void LoadContent()
{
}

protected virtual void Initialize()
{
  this.applyChanges(this.graphicsDeviceManager);
  this.InitializeExistingComponents();
  this._graphicsDeviceService = (IGraphicsDeviceService) this.Services.GetService(typeof (IGraphicsDeviceService));
  if (this._graphicsDeviceService == null || this._graphicsDeviceService.GraphicsDevice == null)
    return;
  this.LoadContent();
}
```

So, `LoadContent` gets called *conditionally*, if graphics device has been setup correctly. If you want to preserve this logic, leave `SpriteBatch` initialization there.

But if you move it to `Initialize`, nothing horrible will happen.